# database connection from dreamviewer to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

Actually I had created a new site in dreamviewer.

Now, when I am going to connect the connection using MySQL connection I had fill up all the information as below:

```
connection name : myconnection
mysqlserver :  localhost
username : root 
password:*****
```

I am getting the error that “`an undefined error has occurred`” after selecting the database?

How can I select the database?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this:

Since `mysql_*` is deprecated so use `mysqli` or `PDO`

```
<?php
$server     =   "HOST";
$database   =   "DBNAME";
$user       =   "DATABASEUSER";
$password   =   "PASSWORD";

    $con    =   mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have phpmyadmin first test the connections with that. In case you have to do it explicitly with Dreamweaver, essure the following

- Its your localhost only, not outside your server
- Check your DreamWeaver version compatibility with APACHE/PHP releases. Perhaps you may need to downgrade DW
- Double check `URL Prefix` in MX portion.
- Ownership of files/directories. Proper privilege to overwrite your `.php` file